# Get the number of columns in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the number of columns in a table if that makes sense. For example, I have 5 tables with a column in each. Instead of getting the sum of all data in those columns, I would like to get the sum of how many there are. If that makes sense?

Here is a diagram of what I mean:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public function getNumber() {
    include("dbconnect.php");
    $query = "SELECT 
            (SELECT username FROM table1)
            + (SELECT username FROM table2)
            + (SELECT username FROM table3)
            + (SELECT username FROM table4)
            + (SELECT username FROM table5)";
    $result = mysqli_query($scriptdatasqlcon, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
    } else {
        echo "UH OH";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the number of columns, or the number of rows?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-fields.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use COUNT(*) - e.g.

```
$query = "SELECT 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1)
        + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2)
        + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3)
        + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table4)
        + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table5)";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

```
SELECT COUNT(username) from table1
```

Give you the number of rows that got an username not equal to null.

In your case, you probably want to use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from table1
```

Which give you the number of row in the table1.

For your specific case :

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) from table1) + (SELECT COUNT(*) from table2) ... (SELECT COUNT(*) from table5) AS totalRow`
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need this;

```
Select (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) as Total
```

Hope Helps,